# Moments Properties of Orthonormal Basis

Tags: orthonormal

The first and second moments properties of an orthonormal basis $\{u_j\}_{j \geq 1}$ are well known:
$$ \int_{t\in \mathcal{T}} u_j(t) F(dt)=0  $$
$$ \int_{t\in \mathcal{T}} u^2_j(t) F(dt)=1 $$
and
$$ \int_{t\in \mathcal{T}} u_j(t) u_i(t) F(dt)=0,\quad i\neq j $$

I am curious, what are fourth moment properties of $\{u_j\}_{j \geq 1}$, i.e.,
$$  \int_{t\in \mathcal{T}} u^4_j(t) F(dt) = ?  $$
and
$$  \int_{t\in \mathcal{T}} u^2_j(t) u^2_i(t) F(dt) = ?  $$

Comment: The first equality is not true. Consider for example the first element of the Legendre polynomials.